# How to create the standard pdf_document template with rmarkdown::draft()?

Tags: r, r-markdown

`rmarkdown::draft()` creates template files from many different templates, the same way using `File -> New File -> R markdown` in Rstudio would do.

Although I can reproduce the usage examples from the package, specifying the template and package name

```
rmarkdown::draft("Q4Report.Rmd", template="quarterly_report", package="pubtools")
```

or

```
rmarkdown::draft("myfile.Rmd",template="xaringan", package="xaringan")
```

I'm unable to find out how to create the "standard" `html_document` and `pdf_document` templates.

```
rmarkdown::draft("myfile.Rmd",template="pdf_document")
```

returns an error message that the template was not found.

Looking at [`rmarkdown`'s Github repository](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/tree/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates) I realized there are only the templates called `html_vignette` and `github_document` in the package. My question is:

Where are the "standard" `pdf_document` and `html_document` templates? Do they belong to another package or `rmarkdown::draft()` is unable to create these templates for some reason?